# Is it ok for companies to withhold wages mid pay peroid after termination?

Tags: employees

I was hired on by a restaurant place local to my area.  I was a cook there, and everything was going swell.  Then, out of the blue on Christmas Eve day, I walk in doing my normal routine, in comes boss.  Then out comes the words, "You are no longer needed have a good time."  I live in an Employer friendly state first off.  I was expecting this to happen, even though I do follow the rules and have not caused trouble for anyone.  Mind you got paid same day.  So I would get paid in 2 weeks and that's the end of that.

To my dismay I found out my employer did not file my time for that weeks pay period, and further more found she felt obligated since I did not finish the pay period because I was terminated Mid week.

My question is simple, is this at all normal?  Please understand I am in no way looking for legal advice.

Comment: It depends on where you live. In the US, the law typically states that if you work the hours, you get paid--doesn't matter that you are let go prior to a pay period.

Comment: @DA This probably should go in an answer. Comments should serve to clarify or add additional insights per community guidelines I believe

Comment: Can you say 'lawsuit'?

Comment: I am curious how this is OT.  It doesnt seek legal advise, nor does it ask about a specfic company standard.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> My question is simple, is this at all normal?

It's not extremely unusual to be fired in the middle of a pay period. And since you indicate that you were "expecting this to happen", then something must have triggered the immediate dismissal.

In the US, you are entitled to be paid for all of the hours you actually worked, no matter when in the pay cycle you are dismissed.

If you haven't yet received payment for the hours you actually worked, and the day has passed when you would normally receive your pay check, you should talk with your boss. Ask why you haven't been paid yet, and when you should expect to receive your check.

If you feel that your employer isn't going to pay you what you are owed, you may need to contact your state's Attorney General, or the local Department of Labor.

Comment: I believe, by US law, the employer has to provide the last check no later than the next normal pay period.  Sometimes earlier depending on the state.  In other words the OP should have received the check by the normal time: http://www.dol.gov/dol/topic/wages/lastpaycheck.htm

Comment: In a couple of states that I lived in, there were more restricted rules on final pay (within 7 days of termination in AZ).